# ArgumentError with Cucumber and Machinist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, machinist

I am using Cucumber Factory and to make it easy to use Machinist with Cucumber and I am running into an ArgumentError. The line in my feature file that is causing the problem is:

```
Given there is a tag
```

In the blueprint file I define Tag as this (not the best, will be improved once I get past the ArgumentError):

```
Tag.blueprint do
    name                { "tag" }   
    slug                { "slug" }
    uuid                { "uuid" }
end
```

Here's the backtrace:

```
cucumber_factory-1.8.4/lib/cucumber/factory.rb:24
  wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:33:in `attributes='
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber_factory-1.8.4/lib/cucumber/factory.rb:124:in `create_record'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber_factory-1.8.4/lib/cucumber/factory.rb:79:in `parse_creation'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber_factory-1.8.4/lib/cucumber/factory.rb:24:in `block in <class:Factory>'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `instance_exec'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `block in cucumber_instance_exec'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:69:in `cucumber_run_with_backtrace_filtering'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:36:in `cucumber_instance_exec'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_step_definition.rb:97:in `invoke'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/step_match.rb:25:in `invoke'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/step_invocation.rb:60:in `invoke'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/step_invocation.rb:38:in `accept'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:99:in `block in visit_step'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:98:in `visit_step'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/step_collection.rb:15:in `block in accept'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/step_collection.rb:14:in `each'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/step_collection.rb:14:in `accept'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:93:in `block in visit_steps'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:92:in `visit_steps'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/background.rb:41:in `block in accept'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/background.rb:52:in `block in with_visitor'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/scenario.rb:105:in `with_visitor'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/background.rb:51:in `with_visitor'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/background.rb:38:in `accept'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:57:in `block in visit_background'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:56:in `visit_background'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:41:in `accept'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:20:in `block in visit_feature'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:19:in `visit_feature'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:29:in `block in accept'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:28:in `accept'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:14:in `block in visit_features'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:163:in `broadcast'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:13:in `visit_features'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:47:in `run!'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/cucumber-1.2.5/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
  /Users/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
  features/api/v1/source/get_source.feature:7:in `And there is a tag'
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.6, Cucumber 1.2.5, Cucumber Rails 1.3.1, Cucumber Factory 1.8.4 and Machinist 2.0. The blueprint seems fine since Tag.make works in the rails console.

I would be very grateful for any ideas on how to get past the ArgumentErrors!

Comment: The "And there is a tag" in the trace makes me wonder if you maybe could share some more of your Cucumber scenario?

Comment: Even if I run the scenario with just the "Given there is a tag" line I get the error and the backtrace looks the same (except the last line of course).